# ConditionPathIsDirectory=/sys/class/bluetooth was not met

Tags: bluetooth, systemd, services

The output of systemctl status bluetooth is:

```
    ● bluetooth.service - Bluetooth service
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/bluetooth.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: inactive (dead)
Condition: start condition failed at Thu 2020-12-17 01:23:52 WET; 28min ago
           └─ ConditionPathIsDirectory=/sys/class/bluetooth was not met
     Docs: man:bluetoothd(8)
```

I have dul-boot with Win10 and I can use bluetooth fine there. Any help?

Thanks in advance

Comment: This can happen when the Bluetooth device is not enabled during boot time. Does your computer have a hardware switch to enable/disable Bluetooth and/or WiFi?